# GNU makefile syntax for loop in windows

Tags: makefile, gnu

I have a GNU makefile written for linux operating system. I want to compile it on windows but there are some syntax changes for windows. I have done some changes but I am getting an error on for loop syntax.

Make file code is already written and I have to modify it for running on windows OS. Original code is attached and the changes i made are also given
Original code:

This is the original code:

```
@for i in $(subdirs); do \ (cd $$i && $(MAKE) $@) || break; \ done
```

After changes:

```
# pass make directives to subdirectories
SHELL = sh
%:
    for f in $$(subdirs); \
    do \
      (cd $$i && $(MAKE) $@) || break; \
    done

# eof
```

I am getting the error on line 16 which is first line of for loop

`GNUmakefile(16) : fatal error U1035: syntax error : expected ':' or '=' separator`

Comment: Please add the original code in the question. Click on the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56419510/edit) button.

Comment: That syntax error almost always means that you have spaces where you need a tab or vice versa.  Tough to spot by inspection as spaces and tabs look the same...

Comment: But it is giving error for "expected : or = in first line of for loop. May be the syntax for loop is different in windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made certain changes after reading nmake syntax. Now the problem is resolved. 
The %: is not needed and @for does not work. So we need to turn off echo using @echo off: and then for loop will work with simple 'for' keyword instead of @for.
Working code is here:

```
SHELL = sh
# %:
@echo off :
    for i in $(subdirs) ; \
    do \
    (cd $$i && $(MAKE) $@) || break; \
    done

# eof
```